# can't install flutter session package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I'm currently working on my first ever flutter project.
I tried to install flutter session package but it shows me this error [image: error]
These are the packages I currently have [image: packages]

Comment: Your 2 packages are conflicting, can you try to change the versions of the packages that are written there?

Comment: cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  http: ^0.13.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0+1
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.2.39
  provider: ^6.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
those are the packages i got, what do u think i should change?